# how can I get and mark a position in google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I 'm new in google map.
I use this code to show google map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(32.39793603710494,51.39232635498047),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now  I want to mark and get Latitude and Longitude a place when I clicking on it ,I wanted Latitude and Longitude for save in database.How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant add markers to custom tile map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307110/cant-add-markers-to-custom-tile-map)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a custom, shareable and colaborative map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015842/how-can-i-create-a-custom-shareable-and-colaborative-map)

Comment: See [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

Comment: I see all these links.I think your answers isn't related to my question

Comment: Your question wasn't very clear.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

I have put my answer because i not see any relevant ans on both pointed question.

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 1,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.137879, -82.836914),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.651968, 9.478485),
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
// from here you can get where point marker user put and get that let long using 
// Lat = evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3)
// Lng = evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) 
// after this you can do ajax call and save at you server and do what ever you wanted to do ...

    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</p>';
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
});

map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
myMarker.setMap(map);

html 

<body>
    <section>
        <div id='map_canvas'></div>
        <div id="current">Nothing yet...</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

working demo : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/QvNUF/)